# How to iterate a table of information with two different arrays made into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, filter

So my problem is, I have two different arrays, one is just Users, one is Licensed Users.

Let's take for example, users length is 20, while licensed users are 6.
Every licensed user is a user, but not everyone user is a licensed user.
Now, my management team for some reason decided to create two different databases for this.

Currently, I am iterating through the users array to show: User Name, User Directory, Assignment, License, Status. The other fields from the mock up table are: Last Used (when the user last had a license) and Quarantined till (a user goes into quarantine if its license is taken away from him).
The problem here is, the Users array doesn't have the Date and Quarantined Till attributes, only the Licensed users do.

The main problem now comes, when they asked me to make a button to filter from A-Z and Z-A the Last Used and Quarantined columns. I have no idea how to make this happen, as I'm iterating through the array of Users but need the information from another array.

For example,

```
a user: 
String: 
User Name String: 
User Directory String: 
Assigned String: 
Assigned String: 
Display: Block or none (depends if he has license or not) 

Licensed User on the hand has User Directory, User Name, date (of when he was given a license for the last time), quarantineTime (another date of until when he is in quarantine).
```

Now the mock up features these columns User name, User Directory,License,Status,Last Used,Quarantined Till. How would I insert the Last Used and Quarantined till data onto my Users array that I am iterating through

Comment: This is a thorough description, but it would help people answer if you typed out examples of the two arrays, and how they are mapped to the table, or what a combined array should look like.

Comment: Of course, 
For example a user: 
String: User Name
String: User Directory
String: Assigned
String: Assigned
String: Display: Block or none (depends if he has license or not)

Licensed User on the hand has User Directory, User Name, date (of when he was given a license for the last time), quarantineTime (another date of until when he is in quarantine).
Now the mock up features these columns
User name, User Directory,License,Status,Last Used,Quarantined Till.

How would I insert the Last Used and Quarantined till data onto my Users array that I am iterating through

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the structure right, based on your last comment. I suggest creating a joint structure (e.g. joint array) of the two entities, which will be made of objects that have the props of User and also the two props "Last Used", "Quarantined Till" which will be taken from Licensed Users.

Example of the joint structure: ("" used instead of actual data)

```
jointArr = [
  {
    user_name: "User 0",
    user_directory: "",
    assigned: "",
    display: "block",
    last_used: "",
    quarantined_till: "",
  },
  {
    user_name: "User 1",
    user_directory: "",
    assigned: "",
    display: "block",
    last_used: "",
    quarantined_till: "",
  },
  ...
  ...
];
```

In order to generate this structure, you will be iterating over Users, while checking on Licensed Users if the current user belongs to that table as well:

```
const jointArr = [];

// users refers to Users array
// licensedUsers refers to Licensed Users array

users.forEach((user) => {
  const licensedUser = licensedUsers.find(
    (lcUser) => lcUser.user_name === user.user_name
  );
  let lastUsed = "";
  let quarantinedTill = "";

  if (licensedUser) {
    lastUsed = licensedUser.last_used;
    quarantinedTill = licensedUser.quarantined_till;
  }

  jointArr.push({
    user_name: user.user_name,
    user_directory: user.user_directory,
    assigned: user.assigned,
    display: user.display,
    last_used: lastUsed,
    quarantined_till: quarantinedTill,
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I don't know if you are Albanian, but if you are, faleminderit shume!

Comment: @TarikSadiku Glad it helped, please mark this as correct answer if it is. Je i mirëpritur!